# How can I create a vertical / horizontal nested CSS menu?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm absolutely wretched at CSS, and primarily a hardware guru / guy who's just learning to write html / css. I inherited some not-so-great CSS menus on our company site, and I'm trying to add a second-level nested menu because we're starting to have some break-out departmental pages. Also, I'm pretty sure a ton of our '.vertical-nav' stuff isn't even used, and just cluttering up our custom CSS. Any help would be appreciated... I'm learning, but CSS is most definitely a bit trickier than I thought it'd be.

```css
.vertical-nav {
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 5s; 
    transition: background-color 5s;
}
.vertical-nav li {
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear:both;
    width: 230px;  
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s; 
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover {
    background-color:#9FB6CD;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.vertical-nav li a {

    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#35586C;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li.current {
    background-color:#517693;
}
.vertical-nav li.current a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:125px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:-5px;
    position:relative;
    top: -40px;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul li {
    background-color:#555555;
    width:125px;
    height:30px;
    padding: 8px 0;

    display:inline-block;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color:#333333;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li ul {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover .sub-menu
{
    display: table;
}
.sub-menu li
{
    width: 230px;
    min-width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;  
    display:table-row;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:250px; 
    top: -43px;
    left: -20px;
}
.sub-menu li a
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0px;
}
.sub-menu li ul{
    display: none
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    }
.sub.menu li:hover ul{
    width: 230px;
    min-width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;  
    display:table-row;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:250px; 
    top: -43px;
    left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="vertical-nav">
    <div id="Homehome">
        <li><a href="link">Service Desk Home</a></li>
    </div>
    <li><a href="link">Services</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="link">Web</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Virtual Server Hosting</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">VMware</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Virtual Computing</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link">Printing</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="link">wpa printing</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">Poster Printing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link">Computing Policies</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="link">Operating Systems</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Hardware</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Software</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Mobile Devices</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Printers</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Surplus</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="link">Departmental Security</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">IT Loaner Equipment</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Networking</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Video Tutorials</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Service Desk FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Purchasing a Computer</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Department Specific Pages</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="link">Biology</a></li>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="link">Biology Policy</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href="link">Chemistry</a></li>
        </li>   
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... I'm beating my head against the wall trying to learn nested CSS stuff... I've been able to fiddle my way through most of the site design, but this has stumped me... no matter what I do, the second sub-menu falls apart.

Comment: This will help you :) https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Comment: The first thing I notice is that your last entry says sub.menu, rather than sub-menu. An easy mistake to make that would definitely break your code. Also, check out the :focus-within pseudoclass, so your sub menu doesn't disappear when you move away from the parent menu to select within it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach building a nested CSS menu.

The approach below gives the `.submenu`:

- a `max-height` of `0`
- a `margin` of `0`

and then changes those values when the parent `li` is hovered over.

**Working Example:**

```css
.vertical-nav,
.vertical-nav ul {
  width: 220px;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.vertical-nav ul {
  max-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.vertical-nav li {
  padding: 6px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: rgb(191, 0, 0);
}

.vertical-nav li a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.vertical-nav li:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(163, 0, 0);
}

.vertical-nav li:hover > ul {
  max-height: none;
  margin: 12px 12px 6px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.vertical-nav li:hover li {
  background-color: rgb(127, 0, 0);
}

.vertical-nav li li:hover li {
  background-color: rgb(91, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<ul class="vertical-nav">
    <li><a href="link">Service Desk Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Services</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="link">Web</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Virtual Server Hosting</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">VMware</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Virtual Computing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link">Printing</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="link">wpa printing</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">Poster Printing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link">Computing Policies</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="link">Operating Systems</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Hardware</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Software</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Mobile Devices</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Printers</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">Surplus</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link">Departmental Security</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">IT Loaner Equipment</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Networking</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Video Tutorials</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Service Desk FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Purchasing a Computer</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Department Specific Pages</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="link">Biology</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="link">Biology Policy</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="link">Chemistry</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
</ul>
```